# get row corresponding to latest timestamp in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, cassandra

I have a dataframe as :

```
+--------------+-----------------+-------------------+
|          ecid|    creation_user| creation_timestamp|
+--------------+-----------------+-------------------+
|ECID-195000300|USER_ID1          |2018-08-31 20:00:00|
|ECID-195000300|USER_ID2          |2016-08-31 20:00:00|
```

I need to have a row with earliest timestamp as:

```
+--------------+-----------------+-------------------+
    |          ecid|    creation_user| creation_timestamp|
    +--------------+-----------------+-------------------+
    |ECID-195000300|USER_ID2          |2016-08-31 20:00:00|
```

How can I acheive this in pyspark:
I tried

```
 df.groupBy("ecid").agg(min("creation_timestamp"))
```

However I am just getting the ecid and timestamp field. I want to have all the field not just two field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use window **`row_number`** function with **partition by** on `ecid` and **order by** on `creation_timestamp`.

**`Example:`**

```
#sampledata

df=spark.createDataFrame([("ECID-195000300","USER_ID1","2018-08-31 20:00:00"),("ECID-195000300","USER_ID2","2016-08-31 20:00:00")],["ecid","creation_user","creation_timestamp"])

from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

w = Window.partitionBy('ecid').orderBy("creation_timestamp")

df.withColumn("rn",row_number().over(w)).filter(col("rn") ==1).drop("rn").show()
#+--------------+-------------+-------------------+
#|          ecid|creation_user| creation_timestamp|
#+--------------+-------------+-------------------+
#|ECID-195000300|     USER_ID2|2016-08-31 20:00:00|
#+--------------+-------------+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need a `window` function + a filter for that. I can propose you the following untested solution:

```py
import pyspark.sql.window as psw
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf

w = psw.Window.partitionBy('ecid')
df = (df.withColumn("min_tmp", psf.min('creation_timestamp').over(w))
         .filter(psf.col("min_tmp") == psf.col("creation_timestamp")) 
)
```

The `window` function allows you to return the `min` over each `ecid` as a new column of your `DataFrame`